# Preverify Error with Blackberry net_rim_bbapi_adv_app.jar file

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I've created a simple application that displays an advertisement. I used the BlackBerry Development Guide "[Creating a BlackBerry application that displays an ad](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/40306/Creating_a_BB_app_that_displays_an_ad_1176551_11.jsp)". I followed all steps but I get NoClassDefFound error on the BlackBerry 9900 simulator. I've downloaded the jar files from `developer.blackberry.com/appworld/advertising`

For this I have used preverify.exe to check jar file to be compatible with net_rim_api.jar:

on my CMD:

> preverify -classpath "D:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\com ponents\lib\net_rim_api" "net_rim_bbapi_adv_app.jar" "D:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\bin\output"

i am getting like this,what should i do?

> Error preverifying class net.rimlib.blackberry.api.advertising.app.a
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Thread

i've downloaded the jar's from `developer.blackberry.com/appworld/advertising`

here my code:

```
  import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
        import net.rimlib.blackberry.api.advertising.app.Banner;

        public class AdDemo extends UiApplication{
           public static void main(String[] args)
           {
              AdDemo theApp = new AdDemo();
              theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
           }

           public AdDemo()
           {
              pushScreen(new AdDemoScreen());
           }

        }

        class AdDemoScreen extends MainScreen{

           public AdDemoScreen()
           {
               Banner bannerAd = new Banner(16741, null);
               bannerAd.setMMASize(Banner.MMA_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE);            
               add(bannerAd);
           }

        }
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Post this question with preverify error to the [official blackberry support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev). There are RIM engineers on this forum, and it may help.

Comment: yaa,i've posted in that too,but till no response

Answer (score 0):

To place adds on to your Blackberry Appplication

You can check the below code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rimlib.blackberry.api.advertising.app.Banner;
public class AdDemo extends UiApplication {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  AdDemo theApp = new AdDemo();
  theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
 }
 public AdDemo() {
  pushScreen(new AdDemoScreen());
 }
}
class AdDemoScreen extends MainScreen {
 final Banner bannerAd;
 public AdDemoScreen() {
  Bitmap bit = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("BannerAd.png");
   bannerAd = new Banner(85983, null,60000 , bit);  bannerAd.setMMASize(Banner.MMA_SIZE_EXTRA_EXTRA_LARGE);
  VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(    Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR
      | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
  HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(
    Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
  hfm.add(bannerAd);
  vfm.add(hfm);
  add(vfm);
  bannerAd.setFocus();
 } 
 protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
  if (bannerAd.isFocus()) {
   Dialog.alert("Hellloooo");
  }
  return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: You are posting numerous links to your website without explicitly disclosing that it is *your* website you are linking to.